# Socket Commuication with High frequency

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I need to send data to another process every 0.02s.

The Server code:

```
//set socket, bind, listen
while(1){
     sleep(0.02);
     echo(newsockfd);
 } 

void echo (int sock)
{
   int n;
   char buffer[256]="abc";
   n=send(sock,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
   if (n < 0) error("ERROR Sending");
}
```

The Client code:

```
//connect
while(1)
{
  bzero(buffer,256);
  n = read(sock,buffer,255);
  printf("Recieved data:%s\n",buffer);
  if (n < 0)
    error("ERROR reading from socket");
}
```

The problem is that:

The client shows something like this:

```
Recieved data:abc
Recieved data:abcabcabc
Recieved data:abcabc
....
```

How does it happen? When I set sleep time:

```
...
sleep(2)
...
```

It would be ok:

```
Recieved data:abc
Recieved data:abc
Recieved data:abc
...
```

Comment: use select for your timer.  It helps you with your sockets and your timings all in one!

Comment: 1/ man usleep,
2/ match "send" with "recv" and "read" with "write" rather than mixing them up as you have,
3/ you should probably man read because there are legitimate reasons why read/recv would return -1 that don't mean "recv failed" (e.g. EINTR).

Answer (score 5):

TCP sockets do not guarantee framing. When you send bytes over a TCP socket, those bytes will be received on the other end in the same order, but they will not necessarily be grouped the same way — they may be split up, or grouped together, or regrouped, in any way the operating system sees fit.

If you need framing, you will need to send some sort of packet header to indicate where each chunk of data starts and ends. This may take the form of either a delimiter (e.g, a `\n` or `\0` to indicate where each chunk ends), or a length value (e.g, a number at the head of each chunk to denote how long it is).

Also, as other respondents have noted, `sleep()` takes an integer, so you're effectively not sleeping at all here.

Answer (score 3):

`sleep` takes `unsigned int` as argument, so `sleep(0.02)` is actually `sleep(0)`.

```
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);
```

Use `usleep(20)` instead. It will sleep in microseconds:

```
int usleep(useconds_t usec);
```

Answer (score 2):

The OS is at liberty to buffer data (i.e. why not just send a full packet instead of multiple packets)

Besides sleep takes a unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the OS is buffering data to be sent.  It will buffer based on either size or time.  In this case, you're not sending enough data, but you're sending it fast enough the OS is choosing to bulk it up before putting it on the wire.

When you add the `sleep(2)`, that is long enough that the OS chooses to send a single "abc" before the next one comes in.

You need to understand that TCP is simply a byte stream.  It has no concept of messages or sizes.  You simply put bytes on the wire on one end and take them off on the other.  If you want to do specific things, then you need to interpret the data special ways when you read it.  Because of this, the correct solution is to create an actual protocol for this.  That protocol could be as simple as "each 3 bytes is one message", or more complicated where you send a size prefix.

UDP may also be a good solution for you, depending on your other requirements.

Comment: Or SCTP which keeps the datagrams in order and ensures their delivery, but keeps them as packets, not as a byte stream.

Answer (score 2):

```
sleep(0.02)
```

is effectively

```
sleep(0)
```

because argument is unsigned int, so implicit conversion does it for you. So you have no sleep at all here. You can use `sleep(2)` to sleep for 2 microseconds.Next, even if you had, there is no guarantee that your messages will be sent in a different frames. If you need this, you should apply some sort of delimiter, I have seen

`'\0'`

character in some implementation.

Answer (score 2):

TCPIP stacks buffer up data until there's a decent amount of data, or until they decide that there's no more coming from the application and send what they've got anyway.

There are two things you will need to do. First, turn off Nagle's algorithm. Second, sort out some sort of framing mechanism.

Turning off Nagle's algorithm will cause the stack to "send data immediately", rather than waiting on the off chance that you'll be wanting to send more. It actually leads to less network efficiency because you're not filling up Ethernet frames, something to bare in mind on Gigabit where jumbo frames are required to get best throughput. But in your case timeliness is more important than throughput.

You can do your own framing by very simple means, eg by send an integer first that says how long the rest if the message will be. At the reader end you would read the integer, and then read that number of bytes. For the next message you'd send another integer saying how long that message is, etc.

That sort of thing is ok but not hugely robust. You could look at something like ASN.1 or Google Protocol buffers.

I've used Objective System's ASN.1 libraries and tools (they're not free) and they do a good job of looking after message integrity, framing, etc. They're good because they don't read data from a network connection one byte at a time so the efficiency and speed isn't too bad. Any extra data read is retained and included in the next message decode.

I've not used Google Protocol Buffers myself but it's possible that they have similar characteristics, and there maybe other similar serialisation mechanisms out there. I'd recommend avoiding XML serialisation for speed/efficiency reasons.